# Пробелы в аббревиатурах с точками

Tags: аббревиатуры, пробелы

Ставятся ли пробелы в аббревиатурах с точками? Например, Ф.И.О., м. н. с., п. г. т.

Comment: Аббревиатура это слово. Примеры (Ф.И.О., м. н .с., п. г. т.) — сокращения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аббревиатуры, пишущиеся через точку и представляющие собой самостоятельное слово, пишутся через неразрывный пробел. Напр.: т. е., т. н. и т. д.

См.: Справочник издателя и автора. А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Академический «Русский орфографический словарь» (4-е изд. М., 2012) – самый полный современный орфографический справочник – все подобные сокращения фиксирует с пробелом: и т. д., и т. п., т. е., т. к., т. н. И это вполне логично, ведь пробел – признак нового слова. Мы пишем "так как", то есть в два слова, почему же сокращения этих слов мы должны писать без пробела?

Comment: "Мы пишем так как, то есть в два слова, почему же сокращения этих слов мы должны писать без пробела?" Я-то как раз не считаю, что пробел не нужен. Просто часто встречаю без и нужно себе постоянно аргументировать, что это неправильно и самому так писать не надо. А "Ф. И. О." я вообще так не встретил с пробелами и прежде всего меня интересовала эта аббревиатура. Да и вообще, все мне зрительно больше нравятся с пробелами, в т. ч. и конкретные инициалы, а ФИО, написанная как я перед этим написал, кажется немного странной внешне. Хотя тоже не вижу причин почему она могла бы быть исключением...

Comment: Хотя теперь, когда я смотрю на неё в сообщении, она не кажется уже такой странной, и гораздо легче к ней привыкнуть с пробелами или вообще писать без точек (ФИО), чем было бы смириться с тем, если бы сделали правилом в таких случаях не ставить пробелов. :) Просто я боюсь, как бы при таком повальном игнорировании этих пробелов не сделали нормой писать без них.

Comment: Пробел объясняется тем, что это самостоятельные слова. А если писать ФИО без точек, ее можно спутать другой аббревиатурой ФИО (F. I. О. Free in and out)  погрузка и выгрузка оплачиваются фрахтователем.

Comment: Так такую аббревиатуру и надо писать по-английски или словами "погрузка за счёт фрахтователя". Некоторые пишут, например, imho русскими буквами, я — никогда, не считаю это правильным.

Comment: _Артём Луговой: Некоторые пишут, например, imho русскими буквами, я — никогда, не считаю это правильным._ === См. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%85%D0%BE&all=x

Comment: А почему со "/", непонятно. Я всё равно не буду писать по-русски это, Слава. Кстати, про самостоятельные слова я прекрасно понимал, что **в этом** причина, и считал, что это совершенно правильно, Серж. Просто меня смущало повсюду слитное написание, и мне нужна была "300%-я" уверенность, что только так и можно писать. :))

Comment: А вот, то что "имхо" появилось в словаре - я не ожидал. Все-таки это недавнее заимствование. Я думал, что это слово на периферии интернет сленга и разговорного языка.

Answer (score 3):

> Ставятся ли пробелы...  Ф.И.О., м. н
>   .с., п. г. т.

В **"Русском орфографическом словаре" (4-е изд., 2012)** эти сокращения приведены с пробелами:

***Ф. И. О., м. н. с., п. г. т.***

**P.S.**

Для *посёлка городского типа* возможно и такое сокращение:

***пгт***

Comment: Но  это -- как в словаре. Сам же я никакого смысла в пробелах при написании, к примеру, _**Ф.И.О.**_ не вижу.

Comment: Слава, а вас не удовлетворил ответ Грамоты? А вы сами соблюдаете эти рекомендации?

Comment: _Серж: Слава, а вас не удовлетворил ответ Грамоты?_ === Не удовлетворил. Не вижу смысла в пробелах при написании, к примеру, сокращения "**п. г. т.**", когда его аналог без точек обходится без пробелов: "**пгт**" (так в РОС).